# Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS Fresh Install

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive

This is my df's output. I have 2 disk (1 NVME m2 and 1 HDD) I want to boot with my USB stick again and format my M2 Disk and make a fresh install, but I want to keep the data in sda1 mounted /home (HDD)

Your guidance to make sure I'll not format my HDD by mistake, will be greatly appreciated.

```
Filesystem      1K-blocks       Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev              8064404          0   8064404   0% /dev
tmpfs             1622128       1380   1620748   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p3  119965456    7088932 106739592   7% /
tmpfs             8110636          0   8110636   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                5120          0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             8110636          0   8110636   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p2    1998672     213284   1664148  12% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1     523248       8020    515228   2% /boot/efi
/dev/loop1          56832      56832         0 100% /snap/core18/2066
/dev/loop0          56832      56832         0 100% /snap/core18/1944
/dev/loop2          71680      71680         0 100% /snap/lxd/19188
/dev/sda1      5813265944 5470772680  49450884 100% /home
/dev/loop3          69248      69248         0 100% /snap/lxd/20326
/dev/loop4          31872      31872         0 100% /snap/snapd/10707
/dev/loop5          32896      32896         0 100% /snap/snapd/11841
tmpfs             1622124          0   1622124   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Since you know the sizes, select the "Something Else" and don't format the 5813265944 size disk no matter what the installer calls it. The 119965456 size disk is the one you want to use as / and format for a fresh install.  use /home for the big disk, and do not format.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did a switch from Windows to Ubuntu, and I installed my Ubuntu on SSD. I was worried to lose my data on Hdd so I backed up all my data of HDD. Now after I performed a clean install, it gave me option to select on which disk to install Ubuntu on. So on this step you need to select your SSD and you will be good to go.
After the clean install on SSD, my data on HDD was completely as it is and after the first boot the HDD was auto-mounted in my Ubuntu. Remember your SSD will be formatted during this clean install.
**TLDR:** Select your SSD after choosing the clean install option on Ubuntu installer.

Comment: Did you use Ubuntu Server? The installers are quite different I think